# Merging files one to many

Tags: linux, shell

#### file1.txt

```
10
```

#### file2.txt

```
05--Nov--2010--Friday 23:24:57,06--Nov--2010--Saturday  8:23:34

06--Nov--2010--Saturday  8:23:34,06--Nov--2010--Saturday  9:56:22
```

I want to create a thread file as below[ Using shell script].

#### file3.txt

```
10,05--Nov--2010--Friday 23:24:57,06--Nov--2010--Saturday  8:23:34

10,06--Nov--2010--Saturday  8:23:34,06--Nov--2010--Saturday  9:56:22
```

Comment: It's more like merging than concatenating...

Comment: Will file1.txt always be one line that gets prepended to all lines in file2.txt? Just showing one case of inputs and outputs doesn't give enough definition to the problem.

Comment: Yes file1 it will be always one line. That particular line I want to add with all lines int file2.txt as shown in the example above

Answer (score 2):

```
#!/bin/bash
rm -f file3.txt
prefix=$(cat file1.txt)
for i in $(cat file2.txt)
do
    echo $prefix,$i >> file3.txt
done
```

Comment: `cat` is unnecessary, use `prefix=$(< file1.txt)`. Using `for` in that way will split lines on spaces and output the prefix before each "word" with each one on a separate line. You can do your output once at the end: `done > file3.txt` and you won't need to do the `rm`.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '{print '`cat file1.txt`' "," $0}' file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Or

```
line=`cat file1.txt`;
awk '{print '`echo $line`' "," $0}' file2.txt > file3.txt
```

Comment: Thanks for your prompt support.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk 'NR==FNR {prefix=$0; next} {print prefix "," $0}' file1.txt file2.txt > file3.txt
```

The awk variable NR is the current line number of all input lines, FNR is the line number of the current file:  NR==FNR is only true for lines in the first file awk reads.

Answer (score 1):

Here's an alternative version of glenn jackman's answer:

```
awk -v pf=file1.txt 'BEGIN{getline p<pf;OFS=","} {print p,$0}' file2.txt > file3.txt
```

The main difference is if `file1.txt` has more than one line, mine will use the first line and his will use the last line.